# Ruby - Google Analytics 4, where is the view_id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-analytics, google-api, google-api-ruby-client

So i have a project where i use 'google/apis/analytics_v3' to make some requests and get some data, the thing is that i need a view_id to do that.

@service.get_ga_data(VIEW_ID, @start_date, @end_date, 'ga:users').totals_for_all_results

the thing is that, on the new version of the analytics we don't have the view_id and i cannot find a way in ruby to do the same that this does.

Someone knows how to migrate to GA4 in ruby on rails, i can't find much documentation. We are talking about server side requests to google.

Thanks in advance to someone who can help me

I went over the GA4 configs trying to find the view_id, i've seen that this will be deprecated.
I've tried find other gems to make the requests and the authentication
Went to the github of the gem to check for updates.

Couldn't find a way

Answer (score 0):

The 'google/apis/analytics_v3' library is for use with Universal analytics and requires a view id.

You need to use the [Google analytics data api](https://cloud.google.com/ruby/docs/reference/google-analytics-data/latest) to access google analytics ga4 accounts.

```
require "google/analytics/data"

Google::Analytics::Data.configure do |config|
  config.credentials = "path/to/keyfile.json"
end

client = Google::Analytics::Data.analytics_data
```

Comment: Ty, theres any documentation of how to use that api?

Right now i'm getting an error running the reports

debug_error_string:{UNKNOWN:DNS resolution failed for analyticsdata.googleapis.com: C-ares status is not ARES_SUCCESS qtype=A name=analyticsdata.googleapis.com is_balancer=0: Timeout while contacting DNS servers 

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/properties/runReport

Comment: You have the full documentation page there [Data api v1](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1).   I don't know Ruby but you may be able to find some authorization tips in the [Google cloud ruby client ](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby#authentication)

Comment: Ty you helped a lot.

It's weird,because sometimes i get results and most of the time the run_report is returning Exception: 14:DNS resolution failed for analyticsdata.googleapis.com

not sure waht's happening, but gonna do more tests

Thanks again

Comment: if its dns related its probably a network issue on your end